# Slide to delete cell in UITableview with Parse WITHOUT refreshing tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

Currently I am able to delete a table view cell that I swipe to delete. However, the cell deletion is only animated AFTER I refresh the UITableView. I would like for the cell to delete as I press the red delete button after swiping to delete instead of having to refresh it every time that I delete a cell. Here is my code for reference:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"fgrep";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"name";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = NO;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    //self.objectsPerPage = 10;
 }
 return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                             name:@"refreshTable"
                                           object:nil];

 }
 - (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
 {
// Reload the recipes
[self loadObjects];
 }


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
 }

 - (PFQuery *)queryForTable

 {
PFQuery *fgquery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"fgrep"];
[fgquery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];


// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
/*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
 query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
 }*/

//    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

return fgquery;
 }
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
 {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FGRepCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name" ];

UILabel *operationtime = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
operationtime.text = [object objectForKey:@"fgoperation"];

UILabel *yards = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
yards.text = [object objectForKey:@"fgyards"];

UILabel *hashe = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:104];
hashe.text = [object objectForKey:@"fghash"];

UILabel *makeormiss = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:105];
makeormiss.text = [object objectForKey:@"fgmakeormiss"];

return cell;
 }
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return YES;
 }


 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


// Remove the row from data model
PFObject *objectToDel = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[objectToDel deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    [self loadView];
}
 ];
 }}

 - (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
 {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }





 @end
```

I believe that my main problem has something to do with this code snippet:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


// Remove the row from data model
PFObject *objectToDel = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[objectToDel deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    [self loadView];
}
 ];
 }}
```

Once again, I am able to delete the cell from the table view after swiping and pressing the red Delete button, but the deletion of the cell is only animated after the table view is refreshed. I would like to delete the cell once I press the red delete button which is shown after swiping the cell.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and/or up vote any answers that proved useful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading the tableview, you'll need to:

1. delete the object from your local data source
2. call `beginUpdates`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `endUpdates` on your tableView

Comment: If you are only doing one call to modify the rows you don't need to call begin and end updates.

You only need to call those if you want to do multiple changes, like deleting two sets of rows or deleting a set and inserting another, etc.